# Disable JS Popup Script On Specific Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

[!Newbie alert!] I'm using a ecommerce platform that doesn't allow me to edit the source code. I can only add new codes (html, js or css) to try to do the modifications I want. And what I want to do is to find a way to disable the script of a newsletter popup on only one specific page. The only way I thought of doing it is adding an extra JS script limiting the action of the previous script that I am not allowed to edit. Is it possible to do?

The original script for de Newsletter Popup is this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    
      iniciarModalNews();
    
  });
  function iniciarModalNews() {
    if (!$.cookie('showModalNews')) {
      
      
              showModalNews();
      
      
    };
  }
  function showModalNews() {
    $.fancybox.open({
      type: 'html',
      minWidth: 270,
      maxWidth: 350,
      content: $('#modalNewsletter'),
      beforeClose: function() {
        $.cookie('showModalNews', 'hide', {
          expires: 1,
          path: '/'
        });
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

It runs on all pages of the website and I want to exclude just one page. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: In javascript you can check the url of the current page, look up "window.location.href" - you can then check that is not equal to the specific url you want to exclude.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

Comment: @ChrisCousins that worked great. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full Disclosure: This suggestion would not be considered a best practice but if its a one-off scenario where you don't have access to the source code it'll work.

If you only need to disable this on one page and have access to insert a block of script below the declaration of `showModalNews() { ... }` you can override the showModalNews() function by writing a new function with the same name. The method that calls the showModalNews method is inside an closure via IIFE (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) but the method `showModalNews()` is NOT wrapped in a closure which would give you access to override it.

Example of the overridden method

```
function showModalNews() { ; }
```